# probability using multiplication rule with survey results

Tags: probability

I have frequently bumped into the following question. This is supposed to be sample without replacement right? So after sampling 1 guy, then there's 1 guy less from the population, and the probability of picking another guy should be less than 65%, I guess? So why are they simply 0.65*0.65*0.65*0.65? The true probability should be slightly smaller than this? Thx.

[image]

Comment: Yes, there is one guy less then. But that hardly counts on such a big population. Also I bet that $0.65$ is just an estimation. Maybe "one less" gives an even better estimation.

Comment: In this case $0.65$ is a parameter in Binomial distribution with $n=4$ number of successes=4

Comment: @Alex The OP's (technically correct) point is that it's *not* a binomial distribution since the selected children aren't independent of each other. However, it's close enough.

Comment: good to know the logic is correct. thx bros!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answering so the question can be resolved, but making it a Community Wiki since it doesn't do anything beyond what @drhab said in the comments:)

It is standard to regard draws without replacement as being essentially independent if the number sampled is small and the size of the population is large. In this case, there are 4 children sampled from a population of millions of children in the U.S.

The accuracy lost by this small cheat is less than whatever rounding error led to the estimate in the first place, and the "correct" calculation would round to the same value if taken to the nearest percent.

(Contributed by Brian M. Scott in the comments:) Mathematically deep details of all the above can be found at this [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/explanation-of-finite-correction-factor) post, if you're interested.

Comment: And for more details and some links the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/explanation-of-finite-correction-factor) at Cross Validated may be of interest.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thx! it's a good reference :D

Comment: @HingWong: You’re welcome!